# Use Sugru for fraying lightning adapter on a Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have a 27-inch Thunderbolt display and the thunderbolt connector--not the magsafe power cord--is fraying on the end that plugs into the laptop. I've seen several posts about using sugru on the power cords, can I use it on the thunderbolt cord from my monitor as well? Thanks!

Comment: You can use it on anything you can squish it round, so long as you do it before the individual wires become exposed.

Answer (score 1):

yes, I just did this, it was simple and it worked well! The Sugru pack is abot $12 and it's far simpler than lugging the display in to an Apple store.